# How to create an Amazon Lex Slot type for a URL

Tags: amazon-lex

There seems to be no AMAZON.URL or any other type for slots for urls. I need to capture the utterance like "show {url}" or "show {path}" 
ex: show https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask 
    show /questions/ask
Can I make a custom slot type with regex capturing? couldn't find such an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok you could simply enumerate different url examples in a custom slot type, and it works.

This provides an answer on how to make custom slot types. [Custom slot types in amazon lex without enumeration values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44413621/custom-slot-types-in-amazon-lex-without-enumeration-values)